# kubernetes can you install an entire OS in a pod? And perform selenium tests

Tags: macos, selenium, testing, kubernetes, safari

So i'm trying to find a good way of testing the Safari web browser. I've been looking at kubernetes which seems like a good fit for most browser testing for browsers such as Chrome or Firefox with Selenoid or Moon. Safari is a different beast however. It seems like you need to install the entire OS just to test the browser. So what would be a good solution to this? Should i even bother with a cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot install safari in container.

Safari can be installed only on MacOS, but unfortunately, you cannot run full OS in a container.

Even if you could, I could not help you because MacOS is a proprietary software and macos licence doesn't allow for installing macOS on devices other then Apple's.